# Having one template app and making multiple different apps from it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to figure out what would be a good way of setting up application architecture and how to setup Xcode project itself, in the case where I have one base application, and I need to make multiple applications of it where the all apps will have those same base functionalities but will differ in a way that:

1. Assets may be different
2. Some features can be added ( new screens that uses new endpoints that are not defined in base app)
3. Localization can be differ (eg. one app can only be translated to english, and other can support multilanguages)

and probably some more, but you get an idea of what kind of an app (kinda template app) I am referring to.

What would be a preferred way to implement something like this? I guess targets and making a framework for a shared code is one way to go? Or there is something else that would be suitable too?

Comment: May not apply to your "plans," but worth reviewing [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/), specifically **4.2.6** and **4.3**

Comment: @DonMag Thank you, that is useful to keep in mind. But these apps will only have few base functionalities that are same, eg profile page, search screen... But they will differ in other features. Its only the UI that might look similar. Also there are many apps on the store that literally have same features, same subject, same functionalities, just different names, so I guess it will be all good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target is a good start. Thanks to target memberships, you can "share" storyboards, source files and whatever you want between several targets. Then within each specific target, you add your assets and specific functionalities.

Frameworks can be also a good way to share functionalities between apps. But you can start and try simply with targets, and then later factorize code within frameworks.

The way I would do it could be this way :

- Create your project with a single target, let's call it "Blank App"
- Develop functionalities and prepare generic assets for this app
- When you want to add a new App, duplicate the "Blank App" target, remove membership of default assets, add new ones, add also specific source and resource files, and that's it.

After a few targets, you can spot what can be factorized within frameworks. Add a new framework target, migrate your sources in it, make all apps use this framework, and you'll have a nice system.

Comment: Thanks... Yeah this sound like a good start. I will wait a bit for other answers a bit though, to hear other opinions, but what you suggested make sense...

Comment: Thanks, I already did it this way for an app needing to be designed differently for different firms and some having more or less options, it works quite well.